# Adding Date to an Extract File

Tags: date, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

At this moment I’m working in an export data query that will produce a CSV field in a bucket, something like this.

```
     EXPORT DATA OPTIONS(
  uri='gs://folder_1/folder_2/FINAL_FILE_ _'||current_datetime()||'*.csv',
  format='CSV',
  overwrite=true,
  header=true,
  field_delimiter=';'
  ) AS
select * from `business.DATABASE1.DATA_CLIENTS`
```

But the result field appears with a name like this

**final_file_2023-03-21 08_35_06.663326000000000000.csv.**

And the name that I need is like this.

**final_file_20230321**

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's you updated query.

replaced `current_datetime` to `current_date` and added `format` to get it in format you want and also added part_ to classify the part number to the file. Note, given you have used wildcard(*) in the URI, the option generates several files and hence it is good to classify which part number the file is. hope this helps.

```
   EXPORT DATA 
    OPTIONS(
    uri='gs://for-bihag-pocs/FINAL_FILE_'||CAST(current_date() AS STRING FORMAT 'YYYYMMDD')||"_part_"||'*.csv',
    format='CSV',
    overwrite=true,
    header=true,
    field_delimiter=';'
    ) AS
   select * from `business.DATABASE1.DATA_CLIENTS`
```

Comment: Hello. 

Thank you very much, this is the first time i tried something like this.

Comment: if this has answered your question, pls can you mark it to answered